# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'promise.data.map')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, promise

I'm currently creating unit tests for a project implemented in angular ver. 1.2
I've created a mockService returning a deferred promise to use with my controller tests. A service method looks like this:

```
function getItems() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(["item1", "item2"]);
    $rootScope.$apply();

    return deferred.promise;

}
```

When I call this service method and deferred.resolve is executed I get an error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'promise.data.map')
```

Does anyone know what the `promise.data.map` is and what I need to do to fix the error?

Comment: It sounds like whatever is calling `getItems` is not treating the result as a promise. Maybe if you post the code where this gets called we could provide further insight.

Comment: The result is treated as a promise, but thanks for your suggestion. It turns out it wasn't that tricky at all. There was a method promise.data.map that was mapping the result to another format inside the .then method. Since I was sending strings instead of objects, this mapping failed.

Comment: Why would you choose to return a promise that is already resolved?

Comment: The code is used for unit testing and for my tests it's ok to return the promises resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem

In your question you are trying to call the `promise` before the value of the `rootScope` that have been defined in your controller which is causing the problem. Hence it is returning the undefined value.

Try to define the promise after the `rootScope` values in your `controller`,which may fix the error message

Hope this solution may help you a bit.

Comment: if you face any more problems,then please snippet me the whole code as it is difficult  to check depending upon the little implementation,Thanks